# Inserting a column separator in KableExtra

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have the following table created using `kableExtra`. I'm looking for a way in which I can add a vertical border between columns c and d (to seperate the content under the two headers.) Also, is there a way to change the color of the cells in an entire column (lets say the third column?)

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

a <- c('First', 'Second', 'Third')
b <- c(1,2,3)
c <- c(4,5,6)
d <- c(7,8,9)
e <- c(10,11,12)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

kable(df) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  add_header_above(c("","Header 1" = 2, "Header 2" = 2), bold = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Try piping `column_spec(4,border_left = TRUE)` to your call to `kable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```r
kable(df) |> 
  kable_styling() |> 
  add_header_above(c("", "Header 1" = 2, "Header 2" = 2), bold = TRUE) |> 
  column_spec(4, border_left = TRUE) |> 
  column_spec(3, background = "lightgreen")
```

[image]